# How to Create Shorts in Windows , using spreadsheet input

Tags: excel, vba, shortcut

I like to create some short cuts in windows. The short cuts are going to link to a file saved in a directory somewhere.

In Excel I have a list of file path and in the next column contains the name I like to call the link. I was wondering if anyone could point me to an example of this

Comment: Are you trying to create a shortcut file that could be on the user's desktop or do you want a hyperlink that will open a file by clicking on a cell?

Comment: You'll find the code to craete a windows shortcut here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711040/create-a-shortcut-to-current-folder-on-users-desktop Now all you need is to lookup the code to loop through a range of cells in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your paths are in column `A` and the file names in column `B`, you can type this formula in cell `C1` and copy/paste it in all cells of the column. Formula for `C1`:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1 & "\" & B1)
```